# Python unit test gives AttributeError: 'TestCalculator' object has no attribute 'calculator'

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am attempting some unit testing in python for the first time for a simple calculator. I have the calculator file as `Calculator_steps.py`

```
class Calculator:

def addNumbers(self, numberlist):
    total = 0
    if numberlist == "":
        numberlist = "0"
        numbers = numberlist.split(",")
    if len(numbers) > 3:
        raise TypeError("Only three variables are accepted")
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if int(numbers[i]) > 100:
            raise TypeError("Only values less than 100 is accepted")
        try:
            total = total+int(numbers[i])
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError("Only integers values are allowed")
    return total
```

I have written a test file as `test_calculator.py`
There i have 4 test functions to test addition with one integer, two integers, three integers and one to check for only whole numbers

```
import unittest

import Calculator_steps as CalculatorClass

class TestCalculator(unittest.TestCase):

    def _init_(self):
        self.calculator = CalculatorClass.Calculator()  

    def test_oneIntegers(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calculator.addNumbers('6'),6)

    def test_twoIntegers(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.calculator.addNumbers('5,6'),11)

    def test_threeIntegers(self):
    self.assertEqual(self.calculator.addNumbers('100,6,7'),113)

    def test_DecimalValues(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            self.calculator.addNumbers('5.66,3.44')
```

When i try to run this i get `AttributeError: 'TestCalculator' object has no attribute 'calculator'` for the first three functions. I'm confused as to what the issue is. Can some one explain to me why it is giving this error to the first three and not the fourth.

Answer (score 0):

You import the file `calculator_steps.py` in the `test_calculator.py` not the class Calculator.
Replace `import Calculator_steps as CalculatorClass` with `from calculator_steps import Calculator as CalculatorClass`.